# Calculate the number of jobs reviewed per hour per day for November 2020?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This question is really confusing me. They didn't provide enough details of it. Whatever they have provided I have written below.

- job_id: unique identifier of jobs
- actor_id: unique identifier of actor
- event: decision/skip/transfer
- language: language of the content
- time_spent: time spent to review the job in seconds
- org: organization of the actor
- ds: date in the yyyy/mm/dd format. It is stored in the form of text and we use presto to run. no need for date function

```
CREATE TABLE job_data
(
    ds DATE,
    job_id INT NOT NULL,
    actor_id INT NOT NULL,
    event VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    language VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    time_spent INT NOT NULL,
    org CHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO job_data (ds, job_id, actor_id, event, language, time_spent, org)
VALUES ('2020-11-30', 21, 1001, 'skip', 'English', 15, 'A'),
    ('2020-11-30', 22, 1006, 'transfer', 'Arabic', 25, 'B'),
    ('2020-11-29', 23, 1003, 'decision', 'Persian', 20, 'C'),
    ('2020-11-28', 23, 1005,'transfer', 'Persian', 22, 'D'),
    ('2020-11-28', 25, 1002, 'decision', 'Hindi', 11, 'B'),
    ('2020-11-27', 11, 1007, 'decision', 'French', 104, 'D'),
    ('2020-11-26', 23, 1004, 'skip', 'Persian', 56, 'A'),
    ('2020-11-25', 20, 1003, 'transfer', 'Italian', 45, 'C');
```

Below is the data. Points to be considered :
What does the event mean? What to consider for reviewing?
[image: image1]

And here's the query I've tried:

```
SELECT ds, COUNT(*)/24 AS no_of_job 
  FROM job_data 
   WHERE ds BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2020-11-30' 
GROUP BY ds;
```

Comment: Provide desired output for shown sample data with detailed explanations.

Comment: no they given it in seconds...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below approach if it is what you are looking for.

```
select ds,count(job_id) as jobs_per_day, sum(time_spent)/3600 as hours_spent 
from job_data  
where ds >='2020-11-01'  and ds <='2020-11-30'  
group by ds ;
```

Demo `MySQL 5.6`: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/26

Demo `MySQL 8.0.26`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=83e89a2ad2a7e73b7ca990ac36ae4df0

The difference between the demos  as **@FaNo_FN** pointed out  in the comments is:  in `MySQL 8.0.26`version it will provide an error if date `2020-11-31` it is used, because there is no `31 Novembre`.

Use `and` condition instead of `between` , it performs faster.

You need to sum the `time_spent` for the day.

[image]

Comment: Although it successfully return result in MySQL v5.6 (as your fiddle), you'll get an error on the latest [MySQL v8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7dac72730f2b3c3bb19abf8f4ce908f2). I'm guessing that it's due to default `sql_mode` but the date `'2020-11-31' ` is not valid as there's no `31st` in November.

Comment: Yes to both of your comments. The difference is, the fiddle I linked the version is v8.0.26 which is the very latest and the one in your fiddle is v8.0.11. It's not a big deal, I'm just pointing out the possibility someone in the future who might refer to your answer and come back with a comment like "this is not working for me, I got error".

Comment: i have a little doubt. **as it is written that we have to store date in string datatype then we have to convert it into date format** right ??

Comment: @Chaudhari when you are storing dates in text always should be converted to date,  check my answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190452/search-between-date-in-query-is-not-showing-the-correct-result/69190646#69190646 for further information. `I will suggest never store data into text format`

Comment: @basha04 but as written in question we have to store date in string and then we have to convert it using presto( i never heard of this term). Also no need of date function :/