# Search Between Date in Query is not showing the correct Result

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run a query between dates from Mysql Database and my date format saved in data is **dd-mm-yyyy**

But I am getting the date of the previous year along with the searched data.

Below is my code

`` SELECT * FROM `msr_bills` WHERE `bill_date` BETWEEN '15-09-2021' AND '23-09-2021'; ``

Comment: What column type do you have in `bill_date`? Datetime?

Comment: Its Stored in Text as only Date i.e : 22-02-2021

Comment: Consider changing your schema to store Datetime instead of text, that's what you need to make `BETWEEN ... AND ...` queries. Failing that you can try casting in query time, e.g, `DATE(bill_date)...` or `STR_TO_DATE(bill_date)`. In any case you really should use datetime. Storing dates as text, besides wrong, is a waste of space in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
Select * from msr_bills
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`bill_date`, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('15-09-2021', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('23-09-2021', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM `msr_bills` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(bill_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('15-09-2021', '%d-%m-%Y')  AND  STR_TO_DATE('23-09-2021', '%d-%m-%Y') ;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

When you store data in text format you always should convert it to correct date format

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE `msr_bills` (
  `stuid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `number` text NOT NULL,
  `dob` text NOT NULL,
  `seva` text NOT NULL,
  `amount` text NOT NULL,
  `bill_no` text NOT NULL,
  `bill_date` text NOT NULL,
  `seva_date` text NOT NULL,
  `email` text NOT NULL,
  `remarks` text NOT NULL,
  `unique_id` text NOT NULL,
  `employee_attendant` text NOT NULL,
  `payment_mode` text NOT NULL,
  `gothra` text NOT NULL,
  `rashi` text NOT NULL,
  `nakshatra` text NOT NULL,
  `billing_time` text NOT NULL,
  `anniversary` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).